# Writing list in text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have written this code to write the contents of the list in a text file

```py
    
    def writefile(daymonths):                                    
    filename = "/Users/admin/Documents/Month.txt"
    outputfile = open(filename, "w")
    months = ["{}\n".format(month) for month in daymonths]
    outputfile.writelines(months)
    outputfile.close()
```

but the file shows only one last item, i have tried using outputfile.write(), but still not showing whole list.
textfile screenshot below
[image: file contents goes here to see.]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indentation error in your code. If `writelines()` is not working, then try using for loop. Write for _ in months, outputfile.write(_). Your code:

```
def writefile(daymonths):                                    
    filename = "/Users/admin/Documents/Month.txt"
    outputfile = open(filename, "a")
    months = ["{}\n".format(month) for month in daymonths]
    for i in months:
        outputfile.write(i)
    outputfile.close()
```

Comment: still doesnt work, just shows last item of the list, i believe for each iteration it is overwriting

Comment: Oh wait, I got it. You have to open the file in append mode and not in write mode. I've edited my answer. Try doing that and let me know

Comment: Got it! Never thought of append solution, Thank you very much